# How to unit test a button within an ngfor

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have a button within a nav tag, which is rendered by looping over a list

```
<nav *ngFor="let test of getTests(); let last = last">
    <button (click)="clickFunction() ></button>
</nav>
```

How do I get the click event for the button while unit testing?

This does not work:

```
let button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));
button.nativeElement.click();
```

This gives me an error saying that `button` is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that `getTests()` is returning data and a `<button>` is in the DOM at the point you expect it by putting a `debugger` statement there.  You may need to call `fixture.detectChanges();` if some condition changes that cause `getTests()` to return data and the DOM to be updated via change detection.

I would also use `const buttons = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('button'));` and then index into `buttons` as appropriate so you can distinguish a specific button among the multiple ones.  Setting an identifying and dynamically generated `class` or `id` on the buttons can also be useful in distinguishing between dynamic elements in an `*ngFor`.

I also find it generally easier to use `buttons[0].triggerEventHandler('click', null)` instead of going through the `nativeElement` and I only use the `nativeElement` when there isn't a more convenient method in the `debugElement`.  But you're free to use the `nativeElement` if you so choose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. getTests() was not returning data for me since I was using a mock service